# String function not working on JSON string in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I extracted the following data from an api and converted it to a string to perform string operations on it.

```
import urllib.request
def f1():


    strurl=urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.somedateapi.io")
    info=strurl.read()
    print(info)
    part1=list(info.split(","))
    print (part1)

f1()
```

It gives a type error with the list(str.split())-

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

It is the same error when I try to use str.index('')
Please tell how i can perform string operations on it?

Answer (score 2):

`.read()` returns a byte-string as the error suggests. Use `decode` to get an `str` object:

```
info = strurl.read().decode()
```